# How can I Update two fields in same table with different conditions (SQL)?

Tags: sql

I have One table with two fields that I would like to update where each field has different conditions as follows.

```
one table: TableA

first field1: QtyToGenerate1 
if      QtyToGenerate1 =  0 then
        QtyToGenerate1 = QtyOrdered
Else    QtyToGenerate1 = QtyOrdered - QtyGenerated1

Second Field2: QtyToGenerate2
if      QtyToGenerate2 =  0 then
        QtyToGenerate2 = QtyOrdered
Else    QtyToGenerate2 = QtyOrdered - QtyGenerated2
```

Knowing there are a lot of ways to do this, I would appreciate if you can give me the 'update' and the 'if' clause together because this is what I was trying to do.

Any other simpler logic will also be sure appreciated and I would not mind a little of hints on thinking method.
Thanks

Comment: should be a `case statement` against the field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE TableA SET
    QtyToGenerate1 = CASE WHEN QtyToGenerate1 =  0 THEN QtyOrdered
                     ELSE QtyOrdered - QtyGenerated1 
                     END,
    QtyToGenerate2 = CASE WHEN QtyToGenerate2 =  0 THEN QtyOrdered
                     ELSE QtyOrdered - QtyGenerated2 
                     END
```

Answer (score 1):

should be

```
update tableA
set
field1 = case fieldtotest then
              valuetoreturn
         else
               valuetoreturn 
         end,
field2 = case fieldtotest then
              valuetoreturn
         else
               valuetoreturn
         end
where ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The conditions are utterly unnecessary:

```
UPDATE TableA SET
    SET QtyToGenerate1 = QtyOrdered - QtyGenerated1,
        QtyToGenerate2 = QtyOrdered - QtyGenerated2
    WHERE QtyGenerated1 <> 0 OR QtyGenerated2 <> 0;
```

When you subtract `0`, you don't change the value.  So, there is no need for the `if`.

Comment: In my condition each condition is separate from the other.
QtyGenerated1 <> 0 belongs to only QtyGenerated1
and
QtyGenerated2 <> 0 belongs only to QtyGenerated2